# How to Swap Templates in a Backbone View

Tags: backbone.js

I have a Backbone app that can display a collection of items in two different orientations.  Only one of these orientations can be displayed at a time ('Thumbnails' and 'List') and they each have a separate template.

Is it possible to have just one view and swap out the template (Underscore) dynamically?  If so, is there any example code that shows this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create two different templates, then just check which one to use in `render`

```
render: function() {
  if (this.orientation === THUMBNAIL) {
    this.$el.html(_.template(thumbnailTemplateText, thumbnailTemplateData, thumbnailTemplateSettings));
  } else {
    this.$el.html(_.template(listTemplateText, listTemplateData, listTemplateSettings));
  }
}
```

It really couldn't be much simpler, then just `render` when the orientation is changed.

hope this helps!